# Excel add-in JavaScript - Get last selected cell

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm trying to be able to get the details of the last selected cell - value, address, etc.
So far, I couldn't achieve this - the closest I got to is getting the currently selected cell, which apparently doesn't serve my needs.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "last selected cell"?  Could you post an image?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a reference to the previously selected cell, the following works. Create a global variable called lastRangeAddress. Then assign a handler to the **Workbook.onSelectionChanged** event. The **following** is a handler that turns the current cell yellow and last (that is, previously selected) cell selected blue. The easiest way to see this work is to install [Script Lab](https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380862&sourcecorrid=3c2c9512-e767-40ed-8be1-bab1dc19cb76&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US&appredirect=false) in Excel. Open it in Excel and open the **Selection Changed** snippet. Add the global variable just below the button handler assignment statements near the top: `let lastRangeAddress: string;`. Then replace the **onSelectionChange** method with the one below. Open the **Run** pane in Script Lab, press the **Add event handler** button, and then start clicking cells.

To read properties of the lastRange, you would need to load them and sync.

```
async function onSelectionChanged() {
tryCatch(() => Excel.run(async (context) => {

    if (lastRangeAddress) {
        const lastRange = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange(lastRangeAddress);
        lastRange.format.fill.color = "blue";
    }        

    const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    range.format.fill.color = "yellow";
    range.load("address");

    await context.sync();

    lastRangeAddress = range.address;
}));
```

}

Comment: I've created a snippet that shows how to implement what Ricky's answer describes. You can try this snippet yourself by using Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab) -- a free add-in that lets you quickly/easily test add-in code inside Office applications. Simply install the Script Lab add-in in Excel, and then from the Script Lab tab inside Excel, click the Code button (in the ribbon), and then choose "Import" in the navigation menu and use the following GIST URL:  https://gist.github.com/kbrandl/a768e2c144d2f971366937f7366d47e5